# How do I return an empty result using MVC WebApi 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to return an empty result using a web API on .Net 4.0

I cant use IHttpResult because thats part of the WebApi for .net 4.5

```
Ok(ResultType.NoResult);
```

Is the function I used previously but now I have this chunk which returns my model instead of an IHttpResult.  Whats the proper way to return an empty result?

```
public Models.Login Post(Models.LoginInfo loginInfo)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //throw new HttpResponseException("Failed");
            }
            //Fake Sql Stuff happened here. Dont question it.
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = @"fakeconnectionstring";

                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("LoginQuery", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", loginInfo.Username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", loginInfo.Password);


                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                Models.Login login = new Models.Login();
                // Call Read before accessing data. 
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    login.id = (int)reader["id"];
                    login.Username = reader["username"].ToString();
                    login.Password = reader["password"].ToString();
                    login.Firstname = reader["first_name"].ToString();
                    login.Lastname = reader["last_name"].ToString();
                }

                conn.Close();

                //return Ok(ResultType.NoResult);
                //How to return empty result

            }
            catch
            {
                //throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                //How Do I Throw an empty result
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically a `null` would mean nothing:

```
{
 ...
 return null; 
}
catch
{
   return null;
}
```

A programming note:  Not handling exceptions (e.g. swallowing exceptions) is a potential silent killer of your application.

Answer (score -1):

Best practices indicate that POST should only be used when changing the state of the data/model. Should you wish to return some data after a POST call, you can use a "Post-Redirect-Get" pattern by redirecting to another action.